# Conditional angular module dependency for html2js template script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My node/angular deploy process compiles my angular templates using `html2js`. It produces a javascript file with the results, and is defined as a module:

```
angular.module('myapp-templates', ['/templates/display', '/templates/editor', '/templates/list', '/templates/login', '/templates/pagination', '/templates/signup']);
```

To properly include these, I'd have to add `myapp-templates` as a dependency to the actual app module.

However, in development mode, the `myapp-templates` module won't exist, so angular throws an error. Is there a better way to load the dep or structure the modules so it can run in either mode?

Comment: Do you use grunt as build system?

Comment: Yes. For now I'm using a custom wrapper of angular.module that combines them if it already exists. It works fine, I'd rather not rely on overloading it like that.

Comment: I'm having the same issue using grunt-angular-templates (https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates). The default settings on this package actually add the templates to $templateCache with a `.run` on the app's main module, which would fix your problem. Unfortunately I was having issues with that and I think it's better practice to have it a separate module anyway - so I did something ugly, but it works.


`try { angular.module('templates') } catch(err) { angular.module('templates', []);}`